# POST mywebsite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, post, filter

I am using ajax for handling filters in my custom post type but getting a Bad request on both POST & GET methods don't know why. Here is my Ajax code,

```
(function($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on('submit', '[data-js-form=filter]', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var data = $(this).serialize();
                    console.log(data);
                    var ajaxscript = { ajax_url : '//localhost/experiencecamping/rv-sales/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: ajaxscript.ajax_url,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        success: function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        },
                        error: function(result) {
                            console.warn(result);
                        },
                    });
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_ajax');
```

Answer (score 0):

For this wp_ajax request to work we need to specify action = filter in the data array we send via POST

Also we need filter_ajax() function
Maybe you have it here but you haven't copy it to your question.

Try this version of the code

```
(function($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on('submit', '[data-js-form=filter]', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    
                    
                    
                    var data = $(this).serialize();
                    console.log(data);
                    var ajaxscript = { ajax_url : '//localhost/experiencecamping/rv-sales/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: ajaxscript.ajax_url,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                        query: 'test',
                        action: 'filter'
                        },
                        success: function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        },
                        error: function(result) {
                            console.warn(result);
                        },
                    });
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_ajax');

    
function filter_ajax(){
echo 321;
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting back. I do have a filter_ajax() function and added the object as well but it's now giving me the error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: Ok, try updated code

Comment: Updated code but still have that POST and GET 400 error. The response is showing 0 on postman but they giving the 400 status don't know why! Does that mean something is wrong with WordPress's admin-ajax.php file?